# console.log doesn't print all express session properties in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, express-session

This code

```
router.post("/", (req, res) =>
{
    console.log(req.session)
    console.log(req.session.id)
})
```

prints

> Session {   cookie:    { path: '/',
>        _expires: null,
>        originalMaxAge: null,
>        httpOnly: true },   passport: { user: 'red' } }

and then

> 2sJgQxjBCbKgPiUN3pUdcDty_35GELeE

Is `session.id` stored inside `session`? Why it is not displayed after the first call to `console.log`?

Here is the setup:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:true }))
var RedisStore = connectRedis(session)
app.use(session(
    {
        store: new RedisStore({ url: config.redisStore.url }),
        secret: config.redisStore.url,
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false
    }))
```

Comment: Reasons for downvote?

Comment: Please precise that you're using Express and express-session.

Comment: Added the express tag

Comment: try to use console.dir https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_dir_obj_options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Node.js, `console.log` only displays **own enumerable properties** of an object by using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#wikiArticle).

The `id` property of a `Session` instance is **not enumerable** since it's defined as ([`enumerable: false` by default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)):

```js
Object.defineProperty(this, 'id', { value: req.sessionID });
```

[Source](https://github.com/expressjs/session/blob/master/session/session.js#L26)